# Anaconda プロンプトで Python のファイルが表示されません。どうすればよいですか？

Tags: python, windows

エクスプローラーで確認するとデスクトップにmain.pyが存在するのですが、`dir` コマンドの結果を見るとプロンプトには何も表示されず、ファイルを開くことができませんと表示されます。どのようにすれば表示することができるのでしょうか？

```
(base) C:\Users\yusuk>cd desktop

(base) C:\Users\yusuk\Desktop>python main.py
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\yusuk\Desktop\main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

(base) C:\Users\yusuk\Desktop>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 8283-7910

 Directory of C:\Users\yusuk\Desktop

02/09/2021  01:00 AM    <DIR>          .
02/09/2021  01:00 AM    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  102,505,197,568 bytes free
```

Comment: もしかしてそのデスクトップはOneDrive上のものかも？[【解決】デスクトップの表示をOneDriveではなくローカル上に戻す方法「バックアップを停止」](https://pasokon-labo.com/desktop-onedrive-undo/)

Comment: そのファイルのプロパティからファイルパスを確認しましょう。

Comment: あるいは`C:\Users\Public\Desktop`の方に存在しているのかもしれませんね。